# Showing inequality of series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that:

> $$\Sigma_{k=m}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\le \frac{2}{m}$$

I have tried doing it with induction. If we assume known that $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. We see that it holds for m = 1.

I assume that it holds for m, and sees what happens with m+1:

$\Sigma_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\Sigma_{k=m}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\le \frac{2}{m}-\frac{1}{m^2}$. But the problem with this bound is that after graphing I have that for large m: $\frac{2}{m}-\frac{1}{m^2}>\frac{2}{m+1}$. So it leads nowhere.

Is there an easy way to do the argument? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that for $m>1$,
$$\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\leq \sum_{k=m}^\infty\int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\int_{m-1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\int_{m-1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\frac{1}{m-1}\leq \frac{2}{m}.$$

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to prove a stronger inequality, $\sum _m^{\infty} 1/k^2 < 1/(m-1)$. Just use $1/k^2 < 1/k(k-1)$; this leads to a telescoping sum and the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac{1}{k^2}\leq\frac{1}{k^2-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\tag{1}$$
by creative telescoping:
$$ \sum_{k\geq m}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \frac{1}{m-\frac{1}{2}} \tag{2}$$
that is stronger than the wanted inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: that sum is $\le \int_{m-1}^\infty 1/x^2\, dx.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the integral of $ \frac{1}{x^2}$.